# How do I select all images from a folder? -MoviePy, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, moviepy

I'm pretty new in python and trying to make a python script to put images together into a video(.mp4) using MoviePy.

However, I have multiple files and would like to be more efficient by sort of.... naming the folder and selecting all images within that folder than having to select all images individually.

Here's my Code:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
import os

clips = []
clip1 =  ImageClip('imagesfolder\images0.jpg').set_duration(4)
clip2 =  ImageClip('imagesfolder\images1.jpg').set_duration(4)
clip3 =  ImageClip('imagesfolder\images2.jpg').set_duration(4)
clip4 =  ImageClip('imagesfolder\images3.jpg').set_duration(4)
clip5 =  ImageClip('imagesfolder\images4.jpg').set_duration(4)
clip6 =  ImageClip('imagesfolder\images5.jpg').set_duration(4)
clip7 =  ImageClip('imagesfolder\images6.jpg').set_duration(4)
clip8 =  ImageClip('imagesfolder\images7.jpg').set_duration(4)
clip9 =  ImageClip('imagesfolder\images8.jpg').set_duration(4)
clip10 = ImageClip('imagesfolder\images9.jpg').set_duration(4)

clips.append(clip1)
clips.append(clip2)
clips.append(clip3)
clips.append(clip4)
clips.append(clip5)
clips.append(clip6)
clips.append(clip7)
clips.append(clip8)
clips.append(clip9)
clips.append(clip10)

video_clip = concatenate_videoclips(clips, method='compose')
video_clip.write_videofile("memes.mp4", fps=24, remove_temp=True, codec="libx264", 
audio_codec="aac")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function called `glob` to find all files in a directly which match a pattern.

Eg

```
from glob import glob

clips = [ImageClip(clip).set_duration(4) for clip in glob("imagesfolder\*.gif")]

video_clip = concatenate_videoclips(clips, method="compose")
```

Comment: Thanks, However now I keep getting an error saying: line 75, in concatenate_videoclips
    w = max(r[0] for r in sizes)
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Comment: Would you mind adding more context please? I can't see what `sizes` is and how it's being set.

Comment: Sorry, your answer works perfect! Thank you very much. The error had to do with for some reason Visual Code opening up a copy file outside the folder from the images but now it works fine.